# Switching Firebases in a Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I accidentally added the wrong Firebase (let's call it OLD) to my Swift project, so today I went through [the process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) of adding the correct one (NEW) instead. I deleted the old plist config file and added the new one, but when I run the app, I get an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Provided bucket: OLD.appspot.com does not match bucket specified in FIRApp configuration: NEW.appspot.com'

In the GoogleService-Info.plist file, the STORAGE_BUCKET field correctly is NEW.appspot.com, and OLD.appspot.com doesn't show up anywhere. So how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you specifying the "OLD" name elsewhere in the project (for example where you create the storage reference)?

Comment: @IanBarber That would do it... can't believe I looked everywhere but there

Comment: Hi @mjr, So how did you solved it? I'm having the same problem Thanks

Comment: @KerbyJean I had set up the storage reference with the OLD url explicitly, like `firebase.storage().reference("OLD.firebaseio.com")` instead of just `firebase.storage().reference()` which automatically gets the right url

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem while dealing with two iOS accounts so I would expect the answer to be similar.

The primary reason is that the old user has been cached to your device. This means that each time you login with the newer one is errors due to expecting the old user which is set up on the previous url. Frustratingly deleting the app, cleaning the app, calling pod update, logging in on the new version and calling logout etc don't seem to have any affect on the problem.

This seems to occur when the user has logged and then a new version with a different url is loaded over the top.

The only way I managed to fix this was to reset the app to its previous settings (put back the OLD firebase url and also the OLD.plist google services file). Load up the app and then logout of the app, this should remove the cached user settings. Now when you load up with the new settings it should not log into the previous user (depending on your auto login app settings) and should allow you to successfully log into the new account.

While doing this remember to download the new .plist file and also make sure the correct bundleID and firebase url are entered.

NOTE: If you are experiencing this problem on the simulator I think you can reset the content and settings. This is found in

Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings...

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this via checking my GoogleService-Info.plist.
If you've used the .plist file multiple times, make sure you've added the right one to your project. 
You can always go back to your Firebase console. 
Click on the settings icon next to Overview.
Click on Project Settings, choose the app you'd like to download the .plist file for.
Doing this will solve any issue...